# What does GET parameters mean after image link?

Tags: php

can someone explain what does GET parameters mean after image link (for example .jpg?arg=1&arg2=4...) or how  are they handled?

If it was php link then i can understand that php handler works with parameters and returns smth depending on this params, but when it is sent to image link where are they handled. thanks.

Comment: Parameters could be used for a multitude of reasons. The most common being authentication or cache busting

Comment: Just because the URL calls a `.jpg` doesn't mean it's a static file at all, there may be a RewriteRule redirecting that to a script that will process the output or even validate if you have permission to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive these variables in PHP via superglobal variable:

```
$myVar = $_GET['arg1'];
```

And use it somewhere in your code. [Here is documentation about it.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
Image is generated via `Header` response, and you can call PHP script by `.jpg` extension by appropiate server configuration like `.htaccess` file.

Comment: This is definitely not what this question is asking

Answer (score 0):

It can be some kind of tracking code. Sometimes called a tracking pixel or image.

When the image is loaded, a (php)script can track and store the browser's details, meaning tracking users on the site.

Code example:

```
<?php
/// Show the image (or an empty pixel)
$image = file_get_contents('someImage.jpg');
header("content-type:image/jpg");
echo $image;

// Track stuff (info from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
$remore_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$refering_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$page_requested = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// The store all the info in a file or db to keep track of things.
?>
```

Now the server can keep track of who visits what and coming from where (and when etc.)

Comment: This is very apples to oranges. You're more so addressing the image content itself while OP is asking more about the parameters that follow an image url, and what their use might be.

Comment: I felt that the 'use' could be this example. And that this could give an idea of what a parameter in an image url can mean. It can mean other things too of course.

Comment: updated the answer from 'It is probably a' to 'It can be a'...